# I'm validating the credentials of a user but this function is always evaluated as true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm validating the credentials of a user but this function is always evaluated as true

```
public ActionResult Authorize(string emai, string pass)
    {

        using (WorkFlowContext db = new WorkFlowContext())
        {


            var email = db.User.Where(x => x.Email_Address == emai).FirstOrDefault();
            var password = db.User.Where(x => x.Password == pass).FirstOrDefault();


            //if one of these if true it will send a menssage asking for the email or the password again
            if ((email == null) || (password == null))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "The email or password is incorrect.";
                return View("Index");
            }
            else {

                return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
            }

            }
           // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
```

this part is the form from where I'm getting the values

Comment: You are looking if an email or a password match even if they aren't for the same user. Your .Where clause need to contain both email and password. And encrypt your password.

Answer (score 0):

As @the_lotus has mentioned, the logic there is (dangerously) wrong. You're saying get me ANY user with this password AND ANY user with this email address...which could be > 1 users.

You should try something like this:

```
    using (WorkFlowContext db = new WorkFlowContext())
    {
        var user = db.User.Where(x => x.Email_Address == email).FirstOrDefault();

        if(user!=null) {
           if(user.Password == pass) {
                //all ok - send to home (see my notes below though)
                return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
           }
        }
    }

    //if we get here - something went wrong
    ViewBag.Message = "The email or password is incorrect.";
    return View("Index");
```

...other notes

- Look up ASP.NET Identity - it's a really good system with lots of security features available out of the box covering lots of things you may not think of.
- Don't store your password as plain text
- Be ambigous in your error message - no need to give too much away like *"we found the email in our database but the password isn't right"*